# Need to use older style of Ext.net Slider control

Tags: ext.net

We are using ext.net version 5.2.0 which per my understanding Includes Ext JS 7.2.0.67. I am using  slider control that looks like this ext.net 5.2 Slider: https://examples1.ext.net/examples/miscellaneous/slider/overview/ But I want to use slider that looks like this https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/modern/Ext.field.Slider.html
It seems to me that ext.net 5.2 does not use the updated slider control from Ext JS 7.2.0.67. Any ways  around that?

Answer (score 2):

Ext.field.Slider component I linked to is in the Ext JS Modern library. Ext.NET 5.2 is built on the Ext JS Classic library.
Unfortunately, they are two different libraries with different API's.

One option would be purchasing Ext.NET Spotless Theme, which includes a Slider styled like the Ext JS Modern slider. But Spotless would also style all your other components.